# best swing container for listing threads and their actions?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a multithreaded which does data entry, at a given time each thread is entering similar data. I would like to create a container like the photo I have attached. I would like to update the "Progress" column as the program is working. What would be the best swing component to use in this case?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `JTable` is appropriate. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for details and examples. Also check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial about Swing threading model.

You may also be interested in [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html).